# Why use interface reference for inter-fragment communication?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Currently learning Java and Android Studio. While learning about inter-fragment communications, I noticed that an interface is being used for the fragment to communicate with the Activity. Example:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements communicator{
(...)
public void method(String data){
    }
}
```

interface communicator

```
public interface communicator {
public void method(String data);
}
```

Fragment1.java

```
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment{
communicator c;
(...)

public void onActivityCreated( Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        c = (communicator) getActivity();
        c.method(data);
    }
```

I do not understand the need for the interface communicator. I tried referencing MainActivity directly by changing the c variable in Fragment1.java to object type MainActivity and removing the interface entirely like this:

Fragment1.java

```
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment{
MainActivity c;
(...)

public void onActivityCreated( Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        c = (MainActivity) getActivity();
        c.method(data);
    }
```

It works just the same. I suspect that this extra step (implementing interface) might play a bigger role when things become more complicated?? Can someone enlighten me on this. Is this less efficient or messy? Thank you for your time!

Comment: Interfaces make it easier to proxy stuff.

Comment: Could you elaborate? What do you mean by proxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea behind using and **interface** for communication is to create a cleaner and reusable code.

No matter who implements *void method(String data)*, your code won't break. No matter if it's implemented by an Activity, a Fragment, a Service or any other object.

This is a principle of a clean architecture. Of course it will work without the need of the interface and just *referencing MainActivity directly by changing the c variable in Fragment1.java to object type MainActivity and removing the interface entirely* as you said. But if you want to change your architecture or re-use it elsewhere you will need to refactor all of the code.

This example may clarify it for you:

Let's assume you are using a **Pigeon** as a messenger to send a *message*, If you think Pigeon as a Java Class it could have a method

```
void sendMessage (String msg);
```

Moreover, this method could be part of an interface named **Messenger** and **Pigeon** could implement it:

```
public interface Messenger{
    void sendMessage (String msg); 
}


public class Pigeon implements Messenger{
    void sendMessage (String msg){
        // Some logic to send a message with a Pigeon
    }
}
```

And some where on your App you could send a message like:

```
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment{
Messenger sender;
(...)

public void onActivityCreated( Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        sender.sendMessage("Hello World");
    }
```

This way your app would send a Messenge (no matter how) as long as there's an object **sender** that implements **Messenger**.

If in the future you want to use a **Raven** to send a message instead of a **Pigeon** as long as **Raven** also implements **Messsenger** interface, you Fragment won't break.

Because your fragment does not depend on a **Pigeon** nor a **Raven** it depends on a **Messenger**... Any class that implements **Messenger** is a valid candidate to send a message from the point of view of your fragment.

You should also read about dependency injection

Comment: Ahh I think I understand now. It is so that your code is solely functional and you leave out any initialisations within that may tie your code down to any one specific objects. Thus increasing reusability. Thank you so much for your detailed explanation!!

Answer (score 0):

Using interface guaranties that the `method` method will work with any kind of object which implements `communicator` interface, then you don't need to think about the actual kind of object, weather it is Activity, Fragment, Adapter...

Comment: Okay I understand now, thank you for your response!